# What is there in an Operating System other than the kernel

Tags: operating-systems, kernel

As I understand it, the kernel does all the interaction with the hardware, and manages the memory, the I/O devices, etc. So the kernel is doing everything, yet it is just a part of the operating system. So what else is there in an OS ? Just the applications that come bundled with it ? For example, what does Ubuntu have other than a kernel ? The Gnome Desktop, and a few other applications ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### The shell, of course.

The original metaphor that got us the word "kernel" for this in the first place is too often forgotten.  The metaphor is that an operating system is a seed or a nut.  The "kernel" of the seed is the core of the operating system, providing operating system services to applications programs, which is surrounded by the "shell" of the seed that is what users see from the outside.

Some people want to tie "kernel" (and, indeed, "shell") down to be more specific than that.  But in truth there's a lot of variation across operating systems.  Not the least these variations is what constitutes a "shell" (which can range from Solaris' `sh` through Netware's Console Command Interpreter to OS/2's Workplace Shell and Windows NT's Explorer), but there's also a lot of variance from one operating system to another in what is, and isn't, a part of a "kernel" (which may or may not include disk I/O, for example).  It's best to remember that *these terms are metaphors*.

There are other terminologies.  In IBM mainframe terminology, the "kernel" in the seed/nut metaphor is called the *control program*.  Other names include the *supervisor*, the *monitor*, the *core*, and the *executive*.  Core is another fairly obvious biological metaphor.  It is interesting that so too is another name.   Harvey M. Deitel, in his *Operating Systems*, calls the control program the *nucleus*, and says

> The nucleus normally represents a small portion of the code of what is commonly thought to be the entire operating system [...]

The word "nucleus" comes from the Latin *nucleus*, and means the kernel of a nut (c.f. the Latin *nux*, which means "nut").  So even calling the control program "the nucleus" is in fact making this same operating-system-as-a-nut analogy.  It's an analogy that is used for more than just operating systems.  If you are familiar with chemistry, for example, you'll know that an atomic *nucleus* is surrounded by electrons in *shells*.

What the pseudonymous person `new123456` writes below exemplifies the mistakes resulting from forgetting the origins of these metaphors to the extent that one mistakes the part for the whole and mistakes the kernel for the whole operating system.  Being a "userland" program does not make the shell any less the outside of the operating system, nor make it any less that which encloses the kernel.  Moreover, far from being a DOS-only idea that doesn't apply to Unix beyond version 7, this idea is both widespread and current in the Unix world.

(It is ironic that `new123456` mistakes it for a DOSism.  The kernel/shell metaphor was fairly foreign to DOS in its early years, which favoured *command processor* and similar, from CP/M.  Like CP/M before it, MS-DOS was divided into the *basic disk operating system* (BDOS), the *basic input-output system* (BIOS — not the system firmware, note), the *command processor*, and the *housekeeping utilities*.  The code was actually parcelled up into files this way.  This is another example, in fact, of how the kernel/shell *metaphor* doesn't really cover or fully match up with the *actual* divisions in many operating systems.)

`new123456` is forgetting what Deitel wrote about the nucleus being *a part of* the overall operating system.  An operating system is *both* kernel and shell.  *That is, after all, the metaphor.*  Deitel isn't alone, either.  There are reams of Unix books explaining the Unix-as-a-nut metaphor, from the 1980s onwards.  I recommend Urban's and Tiemann's *Teach Yourself FreeBSD in 24 Hours* (SAMS, ISBN 9780672324246), for the simple reason that on page 54 it has a diagram illustrating the operating-system-as-a-seed metaphor, and — surprisingly — is one of few books to do so.

The name "nucleus" is probably the older name; certainly predating Unix, which favours the kernel/shell terminology that today — probably in no small part thanks to Unix — is the more prevalent.  Here's what's in [Alan C. Shaw's 1974 book *The logical design of operating systems* (Prentice-Hall, ISBN 9780135401125)](https://archive.org/details/logicaldesignofo00shaw/) for example from page 96:

> That part of the system which permanently resides in main storage has historically been called the *nucleus*.  The nucleus will usually consist of a minimal set of primitives and processes for the management of processes, resources, and input-output.

Shaw has a diagram, too, see Figure 4-4(b).  ☺

Comment: I think this is a brilliant answer, simply because it brought to my mind the relationship between the metaphors "shell" and "kernel". I knew both, I never connected them. I knew the answer to the question but still managed to learn something from this answer. Hence the upvote. Thanks!

Comment: I would be hesitant to say this, because the UNIX shell was abstracted from the kernel itself since version 7, and has since a userland program in every sense of the word. What you say is, however, true of a DOS (which is a particularly horrible design choice).

Comment: Well played, sir. However, please leave a `@` somewhere when mentioning my username so that it gets posted in my response queue.

Comment: Upvoted for being such a comprehensive answer with lots of interesting history (I wasn't aware of  nucleus as a computer term - or its Latin etymology). However, I think it would read much better as a stand-alone answer if it didn't explicitly refer to another user's (now deleted) answer.

Comment: ‘The kernel/shell metaphor was fairly foreign to DOS’ – a rather surprising claim, given that the CONFIG.SYS setting that allowed changing the first program that DOS would run to something other than COMMAND.COM was… `SHELL=`. And [it appeared as early as DOS 2.0](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v2.0/source/SYSINIT.ASM#L1411).

Answer (score 47):

Other parts of the operating system include the drivers that interact with the kernel, there are several layers of helper programs that deal with the user interface, the networking and other core parts of the OS that sit between kernel and the actual application.

To give an example, I've shown the [structure of OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Mac_OS_X), as you can see on top of the Kernel (light blue) lies several layers of "core" functionality, system tools, services and APIs (Application Programming Interface) before you even get to the GUI which is what you typically work with in the actual applications themselves.

[image]

Most operating systems have a similar structure, but there is wide scope for differences with regard to just how much is actually part of the kernel. See the Wikipedia article on [Microkernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) for a comparison.

EDIT - To answer your comment (my comment got a bit long)

You *could* boot just a linux kernel, but you would not be able to really achieve much, it's all those helper applications that provide all the interface that you see and use.

Once the kernel is booted (and initialised the hardware) it will attempt to hand off to other parts of the GNU/Linux Operating System which provide the functionality for starting services (such as [UDEV](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) which populates `/dev` with raw device interfaces for programs to use things like hard drives and serial ports and so on) and programs to set up the network ([dhcpcd](http://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd)) and APIs such as [X.org](http://www.x.org/wiki/) for applications to be able to show windows and icons though a Window Manager such as [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/) or [KDE](http://www.kde.org/).

But yes, you could simply boot the kernel itself, it would just sit there with a "I've booted, now what?" prompt.

Comment: so can I boot *just* a kernel and none of the additional stuff that the OS usually has ?

Comment: In theory, I guess, but it wouldn't _do_ anything without other programs on top of it. There are tiny operating systems that people have created for fun that are nothing but a kernel, a shell, and maybe a compiler or assembler (I think Linux started out this way, actually).

Comment: @AnkurVj I've added to my answer.

Comment: I don't think you can boot just the Linux kernel. The kernel reaches a point where it calls init, at which time the system switches from kernel mode to user mode. If init isn't available (or a fake init, like bash), the kernel panics and crashes. So there has to be some init process running to avoid the panic, at which point it really isn't just the kernel running.

Comment: You could boot a bare kernel, but without the remainder of the OS, the user would have no interaction with it.