# Is the word shell a synonym of process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip) article:

> Sourcing will execute the commands **in the current shell**, executing
>   will create a new shell and execute the commands there.

He describes that each shell has its own PID. I don't see any difference between the word shell and process, at least not for how the word shell is used in his context.

Answer (score 6):

A (running) shell is a process but not all processes are shells.

All running applications and daemons are processes. The only thing running which is not a process is the kernel (including kernel threads). The kernel, at least on Unix like OSes is launching one (or more) initial hand crafted processes, usually called `init`. These processes are the parents of a whole hierarchy of other processes. When you run the `ps` or the `top` command, you'll see each process with its own distinct `PID`.

When you log in to a terminal emulator, you are launching an interactive shell, for example `sh`, `dash`, `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh` and the likes. These shells are interpreting the commands you are typing in the terminal window, for example `ls`, `cat` and `date`. The latter are not shells but executable binaries.

You can also run shell scripts, which are text files containing commands to be executed by a shell.

As not all programs are shell scripts or interactive shell sessions, you cannot say shell is synonymous of process.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of such a process that is not a shell?

Comment: How the word shell is used in the article I linked to, I could just as well read process right?

Comment: @Bentley4 Any process that is not a shell is… another process. Starting from the `init` process, or a `vim` editor, or some daemon, etc. If you like Venn diagrams: http://i.stack.imgur.com/scZJV.png

Comment: Yea, but can you give a functional difference (some action/characteristic that returns a different output) of a process that is a shell as opposed to a process that is not a shell?

Answer (score 4):

### No.  A shell is a kind of *program*.

And in context the writer is talking about processes executing that particular type of program: *shell processes*.  That sentence is simply written in an abbreviated form (and missing a conjunction, too).  It could have been written:

> Sourcing a script will execute the commands in the current shell process, whereas executing a script will spawn a new shell process and execute the commands there.

It was written in a context where it was clear that shells — the Bourne Again shell specifically —, scripts, and processes were the subjects of discussion.  Context is important here.

*shell* is part of the operating-system-as-a-nut metaphor.

### Further reading

- [What is there in an Operating System other than the kernel](https://superuser.com/questions/329442/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092622/340790